# Dropdown list in MS Access from a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I have a valid query in MS Access which pulls data from a linked table. But when I use this query as a row source for a combo box in a form, no data is pulled and the list is empty. What can be the problem?

The Query: `SELECT tbl_activityList.ActivityCategory
FROM tbl_activityList
WHERE (((tbl_activityList.ActivityTeam)=[Forms]![frm_everydayTasks]![lbl_teamName]))
GROUP BY tbl_activityList.ActivityCategory;`

The Datasheet view, when the query is run:
[image: The Datasheet view, when the query is run:]

The property box:
[image: The property box:]

Comment: Add screenshot of the property box of the control where you are using this.

Comment: Also mention in the Question what is the SQL query

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, I have added the query, property box and the result of the query in the post.

Comment: Is the combo box on `frm_everydayTasks`? Then you may need a `Me.Combo3.Requery` after `lbl_teamName` is set / selected.

Comment: Thanks Andre. However, I already have that in my `form_load` function. But it did not work.

Comment: `Form_Load` may be too early. What sort of control is `lbl_teamName`? Is it bound to a table field? Is your form continuous or single record?

Comment: Check your Format tab. How many columns is specified? If it is correctly 1, check if you have a non-zero Column Width. If width is blank, nothing will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.. I just modified the SQL query. Instead of `[Forms]![frm_everydayTasks]![lbl_teamName]` I used `Me.lbl_teamName.Caption` and its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uncheck `Hide key column` when you created the combo box? Access might be hiding the first column.

[image: combo box]

If that's the case, go to `Format` > `Column Widths` in the combo box's property sheet and change it to a non-zero number. This should unhide the column.